# Move Folders based on files in Folder

Tags: powershell

I want to know if this is possible with PowerShell.

1. I have folders that have file within them
2. Some folders have only TIF files
3. Some folders have both TIF and TXT files

I want to see if PowerShell can look in each folder and when it finds a directory that has both TIF and TXT files, move that directory to another location.

I believe I have the base to move a folder but need to see if I can wrap that ability to move based on folder content.

```
$srcfolder = "C:\Work\Test2"
$finalfolder = "c:\work\TestReview"
$combine = "C:\Work\Scripts\Tools\ImageMagick\convert.exe "
$arg1 = " -compress zip "


if (!(Test-Path -path $finalfolder)) {
  Move-Item -Path $srcfolder -Destination $finalfolder -force
}
```

Comment: Should those .TXT and .TIF files have any correlation with eachother? (share the same BaseName for instance) or is it ok to move a folder that has a file called  `ABC.TIF` and another file called `DEF.TXT` ?

Comment: Yes. The folder and the files should be moved.